# Поздняя Античность (два с прописной) или поздняя античность (строчные)?

Tags: пунктуация, прописная-строчная, сравнительный-оборот

> ...до того момента, как Anno Domini CDLXXVII Одоакр – «король рутенов»
>   – не возьмёт Рим и не отошлёт знаки власти последнего императора
>   (которого по иронии истории зовут **так же, как и основателя города**
>   – Ромул), – это время называют тут **Поздней античностью**.

После "города" не надо закрыть сравнение?

И как быть с определением античности? Нашла ***П***озднюю **А**нтичность и ***п***озднюю **а**нтичность...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*...до того момента, как в 477 г. Одоакр – «король рутенов» – не возьмёт Рим и не отошлёт знаки власти последнего императора (которого по иронии истории зовут так, как и основателя города, Ромул), — это время называют тут поздней Античностью.*

Поздняя Античность — термин, полностью: эпоха поздней Античности — время распада Римской империи. Все части могут быть со строчной, зависит от контекста.

Римские цифры в русскоязычном тексте неуместны и неудобны в прочтении.

Answer (score 1):

Зовут так же, как и основателя города, – Ромул.

По совпадению ее звали так же, как и его сына, ― Хадне, Женщина Пурги. [Александр Григоренко. Мэбэт // «Новый мир», 2011]